# sql, работа с оператором LIKE, как правильно построить запрос

Tags: sql

мой SQL выглядит так

```
SELECT * FROM dk_purchase_management WHERE title LIKE '%Apple 13" MacBook Pro with Touch Bar, Intel Core i5 2.4GHz, Plus 655, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Space Gray (Mid 2019)%'
```

в таблице, в столбце title храниться данная

```
Apple 13&quot; MacBook Pro with Touch Bar, Intel Core i5 2.4GHz, Plus 655, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Space Gray (Mid 2019)
```

Все идентично по мимо `Apple 13&quot;` и `Apple 13"`

Как правильно можно построить SQL запрос, чтобы поиск сработал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в базе не должно быть никакаих &quot;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM dk_purchase_management WHERE replace(title,'&quot;','"') 
LIKE '%Apple 13" MacBook Pro with Touch Bar, Intel Core i5 2.4GHz, Plus 655, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Space Gray (Mid 2019)%'
```